# Redimensionamiento de ventana con canvas y scrollbar

Tags: tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

Se que es un tema recurrente en el foro inglés, pero por mas que he leido, estudiado y probado
no soy capaz de encontrar y fijar el problema.

Se trata de que cuando redimensiono la ventana verticalmente con el ratón,
no aparece la parte correspondiente del canvas.

Se cita reiteradamente un problema de redimensionamiento en bucle debido al 
parámetro **highlightthickness** que le hace entrar en bucle. Mi problema es que o entra en bucle 
o parece que no reacciona.

Se usa una imagen,noImagen.800x540.png, [image: noImagen.800x540.png], que debe estar en el direcctorio de ejecución.

Este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
y este el programa:


import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, font
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

IMAGENESPORFILA = 3

class Cuadro(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, imgpath, basewidth=250, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master , *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master
        self.imgpath = imgpath

        self.configure(highlightthickness=0, bg="red")  # sin borde

        if not imgpath:
            self.imgpath = ".\\bigblue.png"

        self.original = Image.open(self.imgpath)    # pasa a formato PIL

        width1, height = self.original.size

        # Reducir imagen a anchura necesaria           
        # basewidth = 300  # -------------------------------------------------------- Restablecer
        self.basewidth = basewidth

        wpercent = (basewidth/float(self.original.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(self.original.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        self.thumbnail = self.original.resize((basewidth, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # presenta imagen redimensionada (thumbnail)

        self.pimagen = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.thumbnail)
        self.create_image(0, 0, image= self.pimagen, anchor='nw', tags='image')
        self.update_idletasks()
        bbox =self.bbox(tk.ALL)

        self.config(width=bbox[2] - bbox[0], height=bbox[3] - bbox[1])  
        self.grid(row=0, column=0)

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, pathdir, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        # Crear Canvas para contener imagenes y scrollbars

        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background="royal blue")
        canvas.configure(highlightthickness=0)   # independizado para probar distintas opciones
        canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")

         # Create a vertical scrollbar linked to the canvas.
        vsbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
        vsbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsbar.set)

        # Create a horizontal scrollbar linked to the canvas.
        hsbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
        hsbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=hsbar.set)

        # Create a frame on the canvas to contain the images.
        image_frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="Green", bd=2)

        arr_jpg = ["./noImagen.800x540.png"]*5
        total = len(arr_jpg)
        for r in range (total//IMAGENESPORFILA + 1):
            for c in range(min(IMAGENESPORFILA, total-r*IMAGENESPORFILA)):
                 Cuadro(image_frame, arr_jpg[r*IMAGENESPORFILA+c]).grid(column=c, row=r) 

        # Create canvas window to hold the image_frame.
        canvas.create_window((0,0), window=image_frame, anchor=tk.NW)

        # tag all of the drawn widgets
        canvas.addtag_all("all")

        image_frame.update_idletasks()  # Needed to make bbox info available.
        bbox = canvas.bbox(tk.ALL)  # Get bounding box of canvas with Images.

        w, h = bbox[2]-bbox[1], bbox[3]-bbox[1]
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox, width=w)

        # ******************* Para hacer las variables accesibles por el evento ********************
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.bbox = bbox
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)      
        # ***************************************

        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nsew")


    def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
    # height is tweaked to account for window borders
        height = event.height
        # self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.bbox, height=height-4)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.bbox, height=height)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()    
    GUI(root,"no_se_usa!")
    root.mainloop()
```

¿Que debo corregir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que ni tu `Frame` ni tu `Canvas` se expanden o contraen dependiendo del tamaño de sus padres respectivos, tienen un tamaño inicial fijo y siguen con ese redenciones o no la ventana. Debes agregar un peso mayor de 0 a la fila tanto de la ventana principal como del `Frame` principal:

```
self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nsew")
```

Es muy importante que hagas esto antes de la llamada da `bbox` y de asignar el tamaño inicial si dejas la altura por defecto (como es tu caso) o el ancho por defecto (que en tu caso si lo especificas, `width=w`), en caso contrario entrará en un ciclo infinito con llamadas reiterativas a `onCanvasConfigure`.

Un par de observaciones más:

- Pasar la altura en `onCanvasConfigure` al método `configure` no es un error, pero si redundante. La altura que el evento proporciona es la que tiene el canvas, por lo tanto no modificamos nada con ello, le pasamos el mismo valor que ya tiene. Lo puedes comprobar de forma muy simple con:

  ```
  def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
      print(event.height)
      print(self.canvas.winfo_height())
      print("-" * 10)
  ```
- En el método enlazado al evento `Configure` realmente **hay que volver a llamar a `canvas.bbox` cada vez**:

  - Si tu canvas no cambia de contenido después de ser creado y de llamar a `canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox, width=w)` en el inicializador no pasa nada, el `bbox` es el mismo siempre, pero en tal caso no necesitamos enlazar el evento ni la función. Prueba a dejar el método `onCanvasConfigure` con solo un `pass` y comenta el resto de líneas y te darás cuenta de que todo sigue igual...
  - Ahora, si se agregan, eliminan o redimensionan items dentro del canvas después de ésto su bbox cambia y entonces debemos actualizar la región de scrooll para que lo tome en cuenta. `self.bbox` es un valor estático que es el bbox del canvas en el `__init__`, si luego el bbox del canvas cambia `self.bbox` seguirá con su valor inicial y la región de scrool no se modificará.

    Por tanto, si prevés que el contenido interno del canvas cambie, debes hacer:

    ```
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    ```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, font
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

IMAGENESPORFILA = 3

class Cuadro(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, imgpath, basewidth=250, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master , *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master
        self.imgpath = imgpath

        self.configure(highlightthickness=0, bg="red")  # sin borde

        if not imgpath:
            self.imgpath = ".\\bigblue.png"

        self.original = Image.open(self.imgpath)    # pasa a formato PIL

        width1, height = self.original.size

        # Reducir imagen a anchura necesaria           
        # basewidth = 300  # -------------------------------------------------------- Restablecer
        self.basewidth = basewidth

        wpercent = (basewidth/float(self.original.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(self.original.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        self.thumbnail = self.original.resize((basewidth, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # presenta imagen redimensionada (thumbnail)

        self.pimagen = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.thumbnail)
        self.create_image(0, 0, image= self.pimagen, anchor='nw', tags='image')
        self.update_idletasks()
        bbox =self.bbox(tk.ALL)

        self.config(width=bbox[2] - bbox[0], height=bbox[3] - bbox[1])  
        self.grid(row=0, column=0)

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, pathdir, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        # Crear Canvas para contener imagenes y scrollbars

        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background="royal blue")
        canvas.configure(highlightthickness=0)   # independizado para probar distintas opciones
        canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")

         # Create a vertical scrollbar linked to the canvas.
        vsbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
        vsbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsbar.set)

        # Create a horizontal scrollbar linked to the canvas.
        hsbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
        hsbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=hsbar.set)

        # Create a frame on the canvas to contain the images.
        image_frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="Green", bd=2)

        arr_jpg = ["./noImagen.800x540.png"]*5
        total = len(arr_jpg)
        for r in range (total//IMAGENESPORFILA + 1):
            for c in range(min(IMAGENESPORFILA, total-r*IMAGENESPORFILA)):
                 Cuadro(image_frame, arr_jpg[r*IMAGENESPORFILA+c]).grid(column=c, row=r) 

        # Create canvas window to hold the image_frame.
        canvas.create_window((0,0), window=image_frame, anchor=tk.NW)

        # tag all of the drawn widgets
        canvas.addtag_all("all")

        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nsew")

        image_frame.update_idletasks()  # Needed to make bbox info available.
        bbox = canvas.bbox(tk.ALL)  # Get bounding box of canvas with Images.

        w, h = bbox[2]-bbox[1], bbox[3]-bbox[1]
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox, width=w)

        # ******** Para hacer las variables accesibles por el evento *********
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)      
        # ***************************************

    def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()    
    GUI(root,"no_se_usa!")
    root.mainloop()
```

Para evitar el ciclo causado por el borde, puedes usar `highlightthickness=0` o también para ése caso concreto puedes simplemente llamar de nuevo a `update_idletasks` del frame interno justo después de la llamada a `configure` para ajustar el tamaño inicial:

```
    image_frame.update_idletasks()  # Needed to make bbox info available.
    bbox = canvas.bbox(tk.ALL)  # Get bounding box of canvas with Images.

    w, h = bbox[2]-bbox[1], bbox[3]-bbox[1]
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox, width=w)
    image_frame.update_idletasks()  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para fijar mis conceptos: se debe permitir la expansión con peso (weight),  y expansión (sticky=“nsew”) de todos los widgets “padres” del canvas, ¿no?.

Comment: Otra. La sentencia:

canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.bbox, height=height)

en el manejador de eventos, ¿es correcta?
Por que buscando en el foro en inglés, creo que no vi ninguna que lo hiciera así.

Pero se me ocurrió que si en __init__ de la clase se hacia “asi”, aquí debía de funcionar tambien.

Comment: Finalmente, abusando de tu paciencia. :-)

¿Que significan/ funcionalidad tienen los iconos de la barra de titulo en tus ejemplos?

Comment: En cuanto a la última, uso KDE Plasma con KWin de gestor de ventanas, el contenido de la barra de título es de izquierda a derecha: **menú** de la aplicación (que se muestra como el icono de la misma),  **mostrar la ventana en todos los escritorios**, mantener **siempre debajo** (la ventana se mantiene siempre debajo de otras que se superpongan), mantener **siempre encima**, **título de la aplicación**, **minimizado**, **maximizado** y **cierre**, se que el tema que uso ahora no es muy descriptivo XD

Comment: Respecto al tema del sticky y XXXconfigure(), a mi me quedó muy claro con tu respuesta a mi consulta anterior. Seguramente no me he expresado correctamente esta vez, pero creo que lo tengo claro.

Comment: Al tema del evento, me gusta no solo que suene la flauta, sino que la flauta toque lo que yo deseo, y para eso hay que sabe que hace cada agüjero. Me llama la atención que en las referencias que he buscado, nadie emplee el **scrollregion**. He probado el ejemplo solo con el paramentro **height** y parece que también funciona correctamente, entonces no se si me funciona por casualidad o porque soy capaz de optimizar el código.

Comment: Respecto al tercer tema. Envídia sana. :-)

Comment: Chemag, estoy un poco espeso hoy... Creo haber comprendido a que te referías con lo del evento, no le había prestado atención al responder porque realmente es un tema aparte del problema original y ni me fijé. He editado la respuesta, a ver si te aclara algo. Cualquier duda comenta sin dudar. Por cierto a mi siempre me costaba sellar con los dedos adecuadamente  los dichosos agüjeros de la flauta, luego sonaba como sonaba... XD

Comment: Entendido. Todo muy claro